# ssh to Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server behind firewall

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I ssh to an Amazon EC2 server and have just enabled the ufw firewall. This terminated my connection and now I can't ssh back in. I assume the firewall is preventing access.

I tried rebooting but no help

Anyone have any ideas how I might be able to regain control of the server?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, EC2 lacks any type of console access. To regain control, you'd have to mount the volume of the affected instance to a different instance and remove the init.d entry for ufw (or configure the config file itself).

Comment: Hi Nathan,

Thanks for the glimmer of hope. I was wondering if it's possible to mount my volume to an Amazon EC2 server that a co-worker has? ie. Is it possible to attach my volume to his EC2 server on his account?

They are both EC2 Ubuntu 21.04 servers

Comment: I don't believe so. It would be easier to just spin up a micro instance of your own (since the cost is very low for these) and mount the volume.